# What is "Last escrow analysis date"?

Tags: mortgage, real-estate

I am looking at the 'Escrow Details' on my mortgage and the "Last escrow analysis date" is listed as as 05/01/15. Obviously that date has yet to come. So what does this date represent?

Comment: Is it a relatively new mortgage? Then it might be the date of the first escrow analysis, reviewing the first year of the mortgage.

Comment: @mkennedy I closed on the mortgage January 2013

Answer (score 1):

Every once in a while, the lender will change the amount of your escrow payment. So, for example, if your property tax goes up next year, the bank will raise your escrow payment accordingly.

Comment: That is not really the question. I understand what it represents but I cannot understand why that date that is being listed had yet to pass.

Comment: Since it's a new mortgage, there probably hasn't been an escrow analysis yet. So I'd guess that they're listing when they plan to do your first one in that field.